# mysql: Is it a good practice to create a regular table instead of a temporary table for a query?

Tags: mysql

I need to put all the result of a query to a temporary table then select from it, but due to the nature of the temporary table, I cannot refer to it more than once in the same query. So is it ok to create a uniquely named (regular) table for this and drop it after the query is completed? Or is there a better way to do this?

I tried using Derived tables but I cannot access it from different blocks.

Comment: @Strawberry, As I understand it, this is how it looks like:

`SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT * FROM foobar) as foo //first block
WHERE (
   SELECT count(*) from foo as f //second block
   WHERE ....
) <= 2;`

I'm not sure with the term though

Comment: Derived tables are (probably) preferable. I suggest you provide provide proper DDLs (and/or) an sqlfiddle together with the desired result.

Comment: Until such time that MySQL supports SQL Server style CTE (Common Table Expressions), a temporary table is the closest you are going to get (if using inline views are impractical). The big benefit of temporary tables (as I see it) is that they are visible only to the current session; if you were to use a regular table, that table will be visible to all sessions... consider the kinds of errors that will happen when two concurrent sessions attempt to create, populate, query and drop the same table. (The benefit of temporary tables over inline views is that they persist beyond a single query.)

Comment: @spencer7593, as I specified in my question, I will name the table uniquely to ensure such scenario cannot happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily a matter of whether it's good practice or not. Whether it's a regular table, temporary table or derived table they all serve a purpose when trying to accomplish a task. Therefore, creating a regular table or a temporary table all depends on you and what you want your application to accomplish at the end of the day.

But based on your problem it seems that you might need to create a regular table in this situation since you require access to the table more than once, and you can drop the table after you're finished with it.

Comment: NOTE: a "temporary table" is visible only to the current session. A "regular table" will be visible to all sessions. For concurrency, the name of the "regular table" will need to be unique to each session.

Comment: @spencer7593 given those precautions is it advisable to implement this method?